# SpringBoot: Bypass OncePerRequestFilter filters

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.0.5.RELEASE app. Using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I have created a Custom JWT based security filter JwtFilter :

```
@Provider
public class JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
...
}
```

But I want to Bypass this filter only for 1 specific request / method:
`"/api/v1/menus"`, when is a `POST`

But I don't know if it is possible in the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` :

```
 JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter = new JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter(userDetailsService(), jwtTokenUtil, tokenHeader);
     httpSecurity
         .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
          .antMatcher("/api/v1/menus")
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can override the `shouldNotFilter` method from the OncePerRequestFilter as below:

```
@Provider
public class JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        return new AntPathMatcher().match("/api/v1/menus", request.getServletPath());
    }

}
```

Comment: in order to include more than one url pattern to be excluded we can use below hack

 @Override
  protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
     return (new AntPathMatcher().match("/swagger-ui/**", request.getServletPath())
       || new AntPathMatcher().match("/swagger-ui**", request.getServletPath())
       || new AntPathMatcher().match("/v3/api-docs/**", request.getServletPath()) );

Answer (score 1):

I used to validate the HttpServletRequest for URI path and use the Filterchain to pass the request, response in chain.

like below

```java
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

....

@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse respone, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

....
String urlPath = request != null ? request.getRequestURI():null;
        String[] splitPath = urlPath != null? urlPath.split("/"):null;
        String currentPath = splitPath!=null?splitPath[splitPath.length-1]:null;
        List<String> allowedPath = Arrays.asList("about","info","authenticate");
        if(currentPath != null && allowedPath.contains(currentPath)){
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
            chain.doFilter(request, respone);
        }
...
```

Better approach is as mentioned in Tom's answer. that's Easy.