# How to ignore OncePerRequestFilter for specific apis

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I created a custom filter for token authentication `AuthenticationTokenFilter` and it is extended by `OncePerRequestFilter`. I configure some APIs as whitelist APIs in my `SecurityConfig`, for these whitelist Apis, I tried to bypass my `AuthenticationTokenFilter`.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().
            regexMatchers("^(?!/webjars/).*",
                    "^(?!/swagger-resources/).*",
                    "^(?!/swagger-ui.html).*").permitAll().
            antMatchers("/healthcheck/ping",
                    "/user" + ApiMapper.SIGN_IN_API,
                    "/user" + ApiMapper.FORGET_PASSWORD,
                    "/user" + ApiMapper.SIGN_OUT_API,
                    ApiMapper.SWAGGER_RESOURCE,
                    ApiMapper.FAVICON_ICO,
                    ApiMapper.APP_ENDPOINTS).permitAll().
            anyRequest().authenticated().
            and().
            // If user isn't authorised to access a path...
                    exceptionHandling().
            // ...redirect them to /403
                    accessDeniedPage("/403").
            and().
            anonymous().disable();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        web.ignoring().
            regexMatchers("^(?!/webjars/).*").
            regexMatchers("^(?!/swagger-resources/).*").
            regexMatchers("^(?!/swagger-ui.html/).*").
            antMatchers("/healthcheck/ping",
            "/user" + ApiMapper.SIGN_IN_API,
            "/user" + ApiMapper.FORGET_PASSWORD,
            "/user" + ApiMapper.SIGN_OUT_API,
            ApiMapper.SWAGGER_RESOURCE + "/.*",
            ApiMapper.FAVICON_ICO,
            ApiMapper.APP_ENDPOINTS);
    }
}
```

I found a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52370411/springboot-bypass-onceperrequestfilter-filters) but I already ignoring at `WebSecurity` configuration. So, why I need to write the same on Filter level.

Where I'm doing wrong or maybe I'm in the wrong context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314176/filter-invoke-twice-when-register-as-spring-bean

Comment: @dur nope, I just want to disable filter for particular api that configured in webSecurity.ignoring().

Comment: Yes, I know. And?

Comment: Duplicate, Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74642554/4972367